# Centering angular bootstrap modal window vertically

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

How can I center this modal window vertically regardless of the size of the contents displayed. In my page, I am displaying an image as a modal window and I would like it to display in the center of the screen. I can align it horizontally, but I can't get it to cooperate vertically. Any ideas/examples of this being done?

I followed this example in my page: [modal window demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2g8HJBzmi6UpimfRooTU?p=preview)

but my actual content of the modal window looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div>
             <img class= "attachmentImage" src={{items}} />
        </div>
</script>
```

Should I be looking to make changes in `bootstrap.min.css` or `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js`or is the best way to approach this with my styles in my own sheet.

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need more information or if I am being unclear.

Comment: Add an id to your div and follow the [instructions here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ "center anything vertically")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly disagree with [1Bladesforhire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3299510/1bladesforhire)'s answer, because the top of the `modal` container becomes inaccessible when it is taller than the viewport height. This is a common issue when centering taller children than the parents, using the `absolute` vertical centering method.

My preferred method of vertically centering a Bootstrap modal is

```css
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  }
}

/* you only need the above CSS. The code below centers the modal trigger button */

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While vertically centred when shorter than the viewport height, `.modal-content` is still fully accessible (even with a height of `300vh`):

```css
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  }
}

/* you only need the above CSS. The code below centers the modal trigger button */

.modal-content {
  height: 300vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only solution I've come across that doesn't result in a tiny modal when the viewport is smaller.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**This property is already in Angular Bootstrap. You can try this. Hope your problem will be solved.**

**Reference**
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

*component.ts* and below *component.html*

```js
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

open(content: any, account_no: string) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true, size: 'xl' });
}
```

```html
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Modal Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Content Area
        </div>
</ng-template>
```